# Algebraically closed Assumptions in Miles Reid's Undergraduate algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I found the book a bit hard to read in places as assumptions on algebraic closedness are not always explicitly stated

A) At the start of *Section 4* he writes from **4.8** (II) $k$ will be assumed to be algebraically closed. However it seems that this condition is not necessary for most of the rest of the chapter, am I correct that he only needs it in *Chapter 4* in two more places, namely

**1)** for the remark on page *80* which directly invokes *4.8* II

**2)** for the second part of the proposition in *4.13* 
$$ k[V_f] = k[V][f^{-1}]$$ which is wrong over R e.g.

Or did I miss out other spots?

**B)** In *Chapters 5* and *6* he does not write an explicit requirement that k is algebraically closed, however e.g. Proposition *6.3* the proof uses algebraically closed (as it should since the statement is wrong otherwise). He does write in *8.8* that "gave way in *3* to considerations over an arbitrary field $k$, promptly assumed to be algebraically closed."  Or should I take his comment from Section *4* to mean from there onwards for the rest of the book

**C)** If it is the case that **Ch5** and **Ch6** assume algebraically closed how much remains valid over non-algebraically closed fields?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have a link to the manuscript please.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: When reading algebraic geometry texts, if you are not confident enough to supply the proofs yourself, the safest thing is to assume that all fields are algebraically closed, whether or not this is stated explicitly (often it is stated as a standing assumption at the beginning of the book or a chapter).

Comment: https://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/Miles.Reid/MA4A5/UAG.pdf

Comment: I agree with you Dan that it is safest to assume algebraically closed throughout, and I can check individual statements and verify whether they use algebraic closeness or not. My main concern/problem is that the book does not have a standing assumption and indeed for large parts of the book the field is allowed not to be algebraically closed, this seems to render the book imprecise in places unless I overlooked something.